# Mark extension as @objc only for unit tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I have a class declared in objective c like the following:

```c
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* lastName;

@end
```

And I have a extension declared in Swift to get the full name of `Person`:

```swift
extension Person {
    var fullName: String {
      return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    } 
}
```

I would like to write unit tests, where I would like to test the person's full name, using the extension. Therefore I create a mock subclass, and overwrite the `fullName` property. However, in order to do so, I have to expose the extension to the objective c runtime using the `@objc` keyword.

Is there a way only to mark the extension as `@objc` only for the unit test target? Does marking the extension have "significant" compile / runtime impact?

I have tried adding a Swift compile time flag, something like:

```c
#if UNIT_TEST_TARGET_RUNNING
@objc
#endif
```

but this results in a compile time error. Any suggestion are welcome! 
Please note, the example is simplified in order to present the problem, and changing the objective c interface is not possible.

Comment: I think it would work if you declared the variable twice with the if else micro like in #if but I would suggest to either expose it or not and don't make the test environment different than the real case because if that's the case then the test is useless

Answer (score 0):

Does marking the extension have "significant" compile / runtime impact?

Not really. The compiler produces a thunk, which is an Objective C method which calls your Swift method. This thunk is what's registered with the ObjC runtime, and it's all that it sees. Among other things, it converts to/from the Swift common currency types, and those used in Object C.

If you want to subclass and overridde that property, go ahead and do that. It's really not a big deal.

Alternatively, you can extract the interface of your class into a protocol, conform to that protocol in your "real" implementation, and create a test double that mocks all the methods for testing.